# Plot $|z^2-1|=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, algebraic-geometry

$$|z^2-1|=1$$

$|x^2-y^2-1+2xyi|=1$

$\sqrt{(x^2-y^2-1)^2+(2yx)^2}=1$

${(x^2-y^2-1)^2+4x^2y^2}=1$

$x^4+y^4+2x^2y^2+2x^2-2y^2=1$

$(x^2+y^2)^2=2(x^2-y^2)+1$

I am trying to bring it to the form of $(x^2+y^2)^2=2a(x^2-y^2)$ but cant get rid of the $1$

Comment: Where do $x'$ and $y'$ come from?

Comment: Maybe you could write it as $|z-1||z+1| = 1$?

Comment: In the very first line you should have $2xyi$ not $2yi$.

Comment: @edm I meant it is rotation/translation

Comment: @Quasicoherent edited

Comment: @copper.hat how does it help?

Comment: @gbox The error persists throughout the rest of your calculation.

Comment: @Quasicoherent thanks

Comment: In the fourth line it should be $=0$, not $=1$. Then you get the desired form with $a=1$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff thanks, Solved

Comment: @gbox You could add an answer of your own instead of deleting the post. But if you really want to delete it, please do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$(x^2-y^2-1)^2+4x^2y^2=1\to (x^2-y^2)^2-2(x^2-y^2)+1+4x^2y^2=1$$

$$(x^2+y^2)^2-2(x^2-y^2)=0\to (x^2)^2+x^2(2y^2-2)+y^4+2y^2=0$$